# What's the best strategy for incorporating jumps into a 3D AI navigation algorithm?

Tags: movement, ai, path-finding, godot, navmesh

I'm trying to make a game centered around  chase sequences in a 3D level with a high degree of verticality and movement options for the player. Basically think Breath of the Wild in an urban landscape but the enemies are constantly running away from you. You and the bounties you hunt are supposed to be constantly gliding, climbing, grinding, and jumping. Thr player mechanics work well enough, but I have no idea how to get the NPC AI to also be this acrobatic. All I can find online are various variations of the A*star algorithm, but that doesn't work very well in a 3D world with a large degree of verticality. So far I have tried:

- Manually training a neural net with "sensory raycasts" that are supposed to constantly detect buildings, fixed jump nodes, fixed exit/goal nodes, and the player. The neural net tries to optimize movement outputs to get the highest score. I subtract from the NPCs score every time I catch it or it bumps into walls. Then I chased the NPC and saved the neural net every minute. After 2 hours it still didn't work.
- The game engine's (Godot) built-in 3D navmesh. Upon detecting the player, the NPC would pick an arbitrary exit node from a list and try to get there before I caught it. This works but the route is too fixed and predictable.

Is there another way I can approach this problem? Is there at least something I can do to reduce the chances the NPC gets caught on walls?

Comment: You mention goal nodes. Do the agents have goals or should they just avoid the player?

Comment: A* works in any number of dimensions, including 3. You just need to prepare the graph that it's searching over to include all connections possible with your AI's move set. A conventional approach would be a navmesh along each floor surface, with off-mesh links connecting any two edges reachable from one another via a jump or a fall. You can similarly add connected nodes for each rail to grind along or  each glide-traversable gap. This graph construction is done as a pre-processing step so you don't need expensive surface sensing at runtime.

Comment: The agents have goals they must reach and they must avoid the player. It's like a game of tag that has a base which is "safe". Also is there a way to combine Godot's built-in navmesh with additional nodal points for when acrobatic manuevers are possible?

Comment: A* only works if you assume the map is like a dense 3D maze. My maps are more like a sparse 3D maze.  Again, think of somewhere like Hyrule Castle in BotW.